# Existing database setup

Tags: flyway

I am just trying to use flyway for the first time. So I put relevant clarifications as one post here. Please apologize. Am trying to make our two development test dbs (oracle) as sync or maintained with version. I have below clarifications on that.

1.Practically we have around 4000 objects in our db. Is this tool compatible and fast enough to handle this many objects?

2. We don't want to maintain data level version control for all the tables. For examples for transaction tables we don't want to sync production and development. Rather some configuration tables or master tables data needs to be maintained. Is it possible?
3. Let us by assume example db1 will be considered here as production and db2 will be considered as development. For that should we have to generate a SQL script manually that includes the entire DDL and all tables dml for db1? or flyway has command/option to do that?

Please clarify the above questions or guide me any documentation to refer to try in test set up to familiarize before to implement in actual project.

Thanks in Advance
Balaji

Comment: How have you been getting on? To me your questions indicate that you haven't yet tried the tool. Flyway simply runs a succession of SQL scripts and remembers which ones have been run by storing this information in a table. I think you'd be better off having a go, and should you struggle, post specific questions to StackOverflow.